# Free JS/TS tool for code analysis and refactoring suggestions

Tags: javascript, code-analysis, refactoring, typescript

Are there any free tools that would analyse the javascript/typescript code base and provide suggestions on code refactoring? Such as extracting functionally similar areas of code into separate functions; using certain programming patterns, organizing the code base etc?

Note that I don't mean things like ESLint/JSHint where they can notice unused variables, check types, identify common vulnerabilities etc, but I'm looking for something that would analyse the logic and flow of the program.

Also, I'm not looking for tools that can help *do* the refactoring -- instead I need something that would provide suggestions on where the refactoring can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Code Climate](https://codeclimate.com/) on my open source TypeScript projects.  It does well to highlight duplicate code and overly lengthy or complex functions.